# How do you retrieve BSTR* picBytes and display bitmap picture in any HTML script?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, activex

I have the following `C++` `ActiveX` interface (which I can change):

```
STDMETHOD(GetPicture)(/*[in]*/BOOL bPicture, /*[out, retval]*/ BSTR *pValue,/*[in]*/ BSTR sName, /*[out, retval]*/ UINT * pSize);
```

and which I want to use to retrieve a BITMAP and display it in HTML. I've tried `JavaScript`, but it doesn't support by reference, I now have the folllowing `VBScript`

```
sub getPicture()
Dim bStrValue
Dim uIntSize
Dim ok
ok=objThs.GetPicture(1,bStrValue,0,uIntSize)

'Document.Write  "<IMG SRC="data:image/jpeg;base64, " & bStrValue & ""/>"
alert("GetPicture")
end sub
```

but I get `Empty` for both `bStrValue` and `uIntSize`, and I get a `Type Mismatch` error if I leave the Document.Write.

Any idea on how to get the image?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a method to return your bitmap, you can create a Property - the property can be accessed from VBScript. There is a MS example that shows these, do a search for "ATLActiveX" - one of the first links should be to the example.

In Section D of that page it shows how to create a Property, it returns a float, but you can create your own Property (following that step) that returns a BSTR - call it something like PictureProperty.

So once the ATL wizard has finished creating that Property, you can implement the method it creates in a similar way to the GetPicture() method that you have already written, returning the BSTR containing the Base64 encoded picture string.

Then you should be able to obtain the picture string from your VBScript with a "Dim bStrValue=objThs.PictureProperty" assuming your objThs is pointing to the correct ActiveX control.

Comment: And how does that property help me get the picture? Could you please explain or pinpoint to another code example? I didn't see the connection between the tutorial you recommended ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/599w5e7x.aspx ) and my issue.

Comment: I've added more in the answer below first paragraph.